# Display Shipping class and shipping price under product name cart woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, fedex, shipping-method

**I have used this code and I have got almost my result but i want to display the shipping price also in front of the shipping class. Could anyone modify this code? Thanks**

[See my result here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OqI2.png)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'shipping_class_in_item_name', 10, 3);
function shipping_class_in_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

$product = $cart_item['data'];
$shipping_class_id = $product->get_shipping_class_id(); 
$shipping_class_term = get_term( $shipping_class_id, 'product_shipping_class' );

if( empty( $shipping_class_id ) )
    return $item_name;

$label = __( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' );

return $item_name . '<br>
    <p class="item-shipping_class">
        <strong>' .$label . ': </strong>' . $shipping_class_term->name . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
$shipping_cost = wc()->cart->get_cart_item_data($cart_item);
```

Comment: Where should i add this in the code?

Comment: Under $label = __( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' );